# undefined reference C++ struct variable COA

Tags: c++, struct

Always shown "undefined reference to the array" for the struct "COA"
It always shown that error when i try to write COA in other function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

void printDiamondlattice() ;
int N;
// creating struct to store
struct format{
public:
string M;
float x;
float y;
float z;
};
int S;
int main()
{
cin >> S;
format* COA =  new format[S] ; //Allocating Dynamic Arrays to store the coordinate for later use

do {
cin >> choice ;
} while( choice < 1 || choice > 4);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
ofstream myfile;
    printDiamondlattice();


    myfile.close();
    cout << N << endl;
}
```

This is the function using the ARRAY of struct COA

```
void printDiamondlattice(){
float q = 0.25 ;
float p = 0.75 ;

ofstream myfile;
extern format COA[];
myfile.open ("Diamond.txt",ios::app);
for ( float i =0; i <= Lx ; i++) {

                //to prevent there is some coordinate larger than the size entered
                                if ( i+q < Lx && j+q<Ly && k+q <Lz ){
            myfile << "S   " << i+q << "   " << j+q << "   " << k+q << endl;
            COA[N] = {"C",i+q,j+q,k+q}; //this is where the error happened
            N++;}

        }}
```

i am using code block 13.12 with the GNU GCC compiler. The project is of type "Console application"

i have try to change something like format::COA[N] but it doesn't work

Comment: `COA` is defined in `main`, and cannot be referenced like this. Instead, you should pass *parameters* (also note, you need the size so you can bounds check!).

Comment: Please fix the indention